# Draw 10 random numbers between 1 and 5 as follows

Tags: probability

Draw 10 random numbers between 1 and 5 as follows:
Draw the first one at random and every other one, choose randomly from among The numbers that were not selected last time.
for example we can't draw 1 1 in row.
be we can draw 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...

so the question is what is the expected number of draws of the number 3 among all 10 draws? , in other words how many 3 do we expect to get ? , Can someone give hint to solve it?

Comment: What do you call the "expectancy to get the number $3$"? Do you mean what is the *probability* to get number $3$? Or, do you mean what is the *expected number of draws of the number $3$ among all $10$ draws*?

Comment: Hint:  Each number is expected to occur equally often.

Comment: Do you know about *linearity of expectation*? The expected number of $3$'s across the whole $10$ draws is equal to the expected number of $3$'s in the first place *plus* the expected number of $3$'s in the second place *plus* ... the expected number of $3$'s in the tenth place.

Comment: Stinking , but if you got 3 in the first place how could you possibly get 3 in the second place , and that leads p(1) =/ p(2)

Comment: @MayyasHaj This is irrelevant. The algorithm for drawing is symmetrical - it does not prefer any digit over any other. Thus whatever method you may use to calculate the probability of a $3$ at some place, that same method gives you the same probability of a $1$, or $2$, or $4$, or $5$. So those must all be the same - hence they are all $20\%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm used to draw numbers is *symmetrical* (with respect to any permutation of the numbers $1-5$) - so it does not "favour" any of the numbers $1-5$. This implies that the expected number of $3$'s is the same as the expected number of $1$'s, or $2$'s, or $4$'s, or $5$'s. However, the sum of all five of those expectations (due to [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties)) is equal to the expected number of draws of *any* number, which is obviously $10$.

Thus the expected number of $3$'s is $10/5=2$.

You can reach the same conclusion another way. The expectation of drawing $3$ on any of the $10$ draws, again due to symmetry, is $20\%=0.2$. This is to say that the expected number of $3$'s on any draw is $0.2$. Now use the linearity of expectation and sum across all $10$ draws to get that the expected number of draws of $3$ is $10\times 0.2 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we can use a combination of probability and combinatorial analysis.

First, let's consider the probability of drawing the number 3 on each turn. Since there are 5 possible numbers to choose from on each turn, and one of those numbers is the number 3, the probability of drawing the number 3 on any given turn is 1/5.

Now, let's consider the number of possible sequences of 10 numbers that can be drawn using the rules given in the problem. Since the first number can be any of the 5 possible numbers, there are 5 possible sequences of 10 numbers that start with the number 1, 5 possible sequences that start with the number 2, and so on. Therefore, there are a total of 5^10 = 9,765,625 possible sequences of 10 numbers that can be drawn.

To find the number of sequences that contain the number 3, we can consider the possible positions of the number 3 in the sequence. Since the number 3 cannot be drawn on the first turn, it must appear at one of the 9 remaining positions in the sequence. There are 9 ways to choose the position of the number 3, and once the position is chosen, there are 4 possible numbers that can be drawn on the first turn (since the number 3 cannot be drawn on the first turn). Therefore, there are 9 * 4 = 36 possible sequences that contain the number 3.

To find the probability that a randomly-chosen sequence of 10 numbers will contain the number 3, we can divide the number of sequences that contain the number 3 by the total number of possible sequences:

P(sequence contains number 3) = 36 / 9,765,625 = 3.68 x 10^-6

Finally, to find the expected value of the number of times the number 3 is drawn in a sequence of 10 numbers, we can multiply the probability of drawing the number 3 on each turn by the total number of turns:

E(number of times number 3 is drawn) = (1/5) * 10 = 2

Therefore, the expected value of the number of times the number 3 is drawn in a sequence of 10 numbers is 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is one point I don't think you get , You can draw 3 in the first draw, but you can't draw 3 twice in a row , you can't draw 3 and once again 3 in row